# How to listen to web requests without persistent background page?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, mobile-safari

I'm trying to port this Chrome extension ( https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adblock-for-youtube/cmedhionkhpnakcndndgjdbohmhepckk?hl=en ) to iOS 15 Safari. So, I followed these instructions:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/safari_web_extensions/converting_a_web_extension_for_safari

But the instructions says to disable persistent background. So, in the manifest I did this:

```
"background": {
    "scripts": ["scripts/background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
```

But without persistent background, it shows this:

[image]

Now, is there any way to make the extension work in iOS 15 safari?
Thanks

Comment: This extension uses webRequestBlocking which is not available in Safari. The only solution is to rewrite the extension to use [declarativeNetRequest](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/safari_web_extensions/blocking_content_with_your_safari_web_extension) API.

Comment: Let me try. Thanks for the tip btw

Comment: Seems, is not supported in iOS 15 safari

Comment: https://webkit.org/blog/11727/release-notes-for-safari-technology-preview-126-with-safari-15-features/